# Scanner not working with while loop

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Maybe my google-fu is just terrible, but I'm having a very hard time figuring out how to do this. I'm trying to get a scanner to read a string, add the inputs, and return a value. I feel like I am just missing something... for example, I'm not sure how to get a variable set to the first double in the scanner.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class adding {
  public static double sum(Scanner input){
    Scanner s=new Scanner (System.in);
    double i = (s.nextDouble());
    double sumAnswer = 0;
    while (s.hasNext()){
      sumAnswer = sumAnswer + i;
      i = s.nextDouble();
    }
    return sumAnswer;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(sum(new Scanner("1.2 2.8 3.9")));
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you passing `Scanner` reference to your method, when you are not using it at all?

Comment: You either pass a `Scanner` object as a parameter of your method **or** create it inside the method, but **not both**. Also you need to decide where your data is coming from: `stdin` (keyboard) or a `String` within your code (again **not both**).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need an `i` variable.

And, as already mentioned, don't have 2 `Scanner`'s.

```
public static double sum(Scanner input){
  double sumAnswer = 0;
  while (input.hasNext()){
    sumAnswer += input.nextDouble();
  }
  return sumAnswer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be resetting the scanner after passing the input.

```
public class adding {
     public static double sum(Scanner input){
     double i = (input.nextDouble());
     double sumAnswer = 0;
     while (input.hasNext()){
          sumAnswer = sumAnswer + i;
          i = input.nextDouble();
     }
     return sumAnswer;
}
```

That ought to work better for you, maybe. I could also be mixing something up there...

Comment: You can do everything inside the loop. No need to call `nextDouble` twice.